# Storyboard view look different in iPhone 5/6 - Constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After two days stuck on this problem I've very close to solving it. What's happening is I have a view that holds buttons/score/best score (labels and buttons). That view is centered horizontally, and it's near enough perfect--it's actually perfect on the iPhone 5 (as shown below).

As you can see from the screenshot I want the score/best score just under the stars, in the storyboard that's the case and on the iPhone 5 it works like that, yet on every other device it doesn't!

Constraints are the bain of my life, any help is greatly appreciated. I will legitimately PayPal you coffee money if you can help me with this.

Why is it that the iPhone 6 is different? I have a feeling it's because the screen size?

I've posted all my constraints and there's actually a lot...mostly auto-generated by Swift.

http://postimg.org/image/efwie4kxl/

Comment: iPhone 5/6 has nothing to do with iOS 5/6...

Comment: Apologies @matt, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Letting Xcode auto-generate those constraints is likely your problem - it'll end up doing whatever it thinks is best, though it is rarely correct.  If the part that's bothering you is that you want the score/best score a certain distance from the stars you should be able to fix that by getting rid of the auto-generated constraints for score/best score, and add a new one that constrains the top of score to the bottom of the stars, and if you have an exact distance you want it to sit you can set the constant to that many points.  Without getting into the storyboard and seeing the details of your constraints it's not possible to give you a more exact reason as to why it's not looking the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the multiplier instead of absolute constraints at the messed up constraints.

[Xcode Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET06R.png)

Calculation :  `spacer.height = 0.1 x window.height`

That way it won't mess up your layout. At least thats my experience.
For further information: [Apple iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/EditingConstraintAttributesintheAttributesInspector.html)